# Hide UIImage on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm want to hide a UIImage on an iPhone 5S only. Everything fits comfortably on my screen using Auto Layout on every device except the iPhone 5S and I would like to hide the logo. Unfortunately, all I can find is showing or hiding items based on whether they are Compact or Regular, which is not a solution since that will also hide the logo on iPhone 6 (for example). Is there another solution I can try?

Comment: you can check screen size and compare with iPhone 5s dimensions. if matches then hide UIImage.

Comment: Just use `UIScreen.main.bounds` to programatically detect 4" devices based on the sceen resolution.

Comment: The comments are correct. Of course, the *real* question is why. If you restrict things to iOS 10 you've already restricted things to (a) two OS versions and (b) three phone versions.

Comment: @dfd I completely agree with you. This is really an exception and the user is not missing out on anything critical it is just the app logo that is omitted after tapping on a login animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments on my original post the solution was really simple using `UIScreen.main.bounds`

```
public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

Then where I wanted to hide the logo:

```
    if screenHeight <= 568 {
        self.loginLogo.isHidden = true
    }
```